# Best place to see examples on how to use Win32 API function in delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, console

well i have been experimenting with the Win32 API in Delphi and I'm unsure on where to look on examples to use them..seeing how the MSDN only show's C++ examples.

I have dug through Delphi 7's help file and well... im a little confused so i will just paste my working code i found and the code the help files shows me, i dont understand how it translates into my working code...unless the code im using is some how butchered up.

so here is the code im experimenting with now using the SetConsoleTextAttribute function

----My code that i know works and changes color----

```
begin
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(
                          STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                          FOREGROUND_RED OR
                          BACKGROUND_BLUE);

  Writeln('Red text on a blue background !');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

----------End working code---------------------

--------Now here is a snip from the official delphi documentation-----

```
BOOL SetConsoleTextAttribute(

    HANDLE hConsoleOutput,  // handle of console screen buffer  
    WORD wAttributes    // text and background colors 
   );
```

> Parameters
>
> hConsoleOutput
>
> Identifies a console screen buffer. The handle must have GENERIC_READ access.
>
> wAttributes
>
> Specifies the foreground and background color attributes. Any combination of the following values can be specified: FOREGROUND_BLUE, FOREGROUND_GREEN, FOREGROUND_RED, FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, BACKGROUND_BLUE, BACKGROUND_GREEN, BACKGROUND_RED, and BACKGROUND_INTENSITY. For example, the following combination of values produces white text on a black background:
>
> FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE

------End Delphi help------

Can someone please tell me what cylinder in my head is not firing on this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Mixing red,green and blue gives white text. No background color defined means black.

Answer (score 8):

> Now here is a snip from the official delphi
>   documentation.

In fact, the documentation that you posted that was delivered with the Delphi 7 help is the MSDN help. The official MSDN documentation for Win32 is written in C and you simply need to learn enough C to be able to read it and map it across to Delphi.

There are small pockets of Delphi specific Win32 code examples and guides to be found on the internet. But these do not cover all of Win32. It is my opinion that if you wish to be an effective consumer of Win32 you must learn enough C to access both the official docs, and the myriad of third party articles and samples.

Comment: @Smasher I think that depends on how the question is interpreted. I think the asker is hoping for a comprehensive set of docs and examples written in Delphi.

Comment: I think this implicitly answers the implicit question in the title. I think this is the best what can be done, I think the explicit question about the cylinder is not really expected to be answered.

Comment: i didnt know my question was so cryptic, is all i was asking was for a reference to api examples for delphi..

Comment: That's what I understood the question to be, mainly from the title.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is the first place I reference in case of Win32 API calls. It is the documentation you want on Win32 API and sometimes it gives an example too. Those examples are relatively easy to translate to Delphi, most of the time those methods are already available in the Windows or some other unit.

Comment: But it shows c++ examples on msdn site.. not an example of how to use that api in delphi

Comment: @Sheep: you could try the JEDI API libary: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/. It has translated a lot of Win32 API's to Delphi.

Comment: i downloaded that, i cant grasp how to use it?